# How to disable internal keyboard for ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, wayland, xinput

Is there an easy command to disable internal keyboatd for ubuntu 22.04? I had Ubuntu 20 where I could use xinput --disable id to disable the keyboard but now the default interface seems to be wayland and I am unable to find a similar command to xinput to disable the internal keyboard.

I tried libinput but it doesnt seem to disable keyboard. I also do not want to go back to the previous interface since ubuntu will support wayland instead of X.

Comment: Have you seen [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1443640/1222991)? There is a possible solution offered that seems to work on some machines.

Comment: @matigo didnt try because of this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443640/disable-laptop-keyboard-on-demand-in-wayland#:~:text=Unfortunately%20it%20didn%27t%20work%20out%20in%20my%20case.%20I%20have%20to%20grab%20the%20input%20by%2Dpath%20but%20somehow%20it%20messes%20up%20the%20touchscreen%20inputs%20and%20slows%20down%20the%20laptop)